# Check this recursive code in a C# webbrowser control

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio-2012, recursion

I need to execute a method based on the visibility of the following html element.

```
<div id="loading" style="height: 201px; width: 793px; visibility: hidden;">
```

the method I used to check the visibility property works fine.

```
 public bool isloading()
                  {
                      string v;

                     v= webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("loading").Style;
                     if (v.Contains("visible")) { return true; }
                     if (v.Contains("hidden")) { return false; }
                     else
                         return false;

                  }
```

I'm using it like this. the app freezes upon coming to this code. need help. I cannot use the `webbrowser1.documentcompleted` event as this is an AJAX call. My only option is to check the "visibility" attribute.

```
 public void battleloop()
                  {
                      if (!isloading())
                      {
                          universalclcikbutton();
                      }
                      else 
                      {
                          battleloop();
                      }
                   }
```

I want the loop to keep on checking isloading() and execute universalclickbutton(); whenever isloading() is false. I know it is calling a method within a method. Would someone please give me alternatives?

The app freezes when it comes to the above code since it is recursive, possibly?

Comment: im postive that there is no other event that i can subscribe to(browsed the internet for hours). and yes im stuck on my approach. is there any way that we can check the attribute of a html element all the time and then execute a method based on the change in attribute. im new to programming so please bear with me :)  .

Comment: Pro tip: when asking questions, don't use all-caps shouting, don't use all bold, and don't demand "ASAP" help - it is a good way to get downvoted.

Comment: oh. new to this forums and just wondering y getting downvoted

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this you can try by using while loop

like

```
while (!isloading())
{
    universalclcikbutton();
}
```

so it will automatically call isloading function.

Comment: ah. my bad. will edit the post need to keep on executing the method in an endless loop till i click another button. i tried this while loop too.
i want to exit the loop when (isloading()) and agian i want to call the method which the while loop is in

Comment: according the code in ur answer it will only execute once.
i wnat to keep on executing the method till i press a button(and of course when isloading()=true i dont wnat to execute. but i want the loop to continue)

Answer (score 0):

got my answer. turns out im more of a newbie than i thought.
i just used a timer control from the toolbox.

in the timer_tick event i executed

```
 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
                  {
                      if (!isloading()) { universalclcikbutton(); }

                  }
```

and whenever i wnated to start my universalbuttonclick(); method i used timer.start();  and timer.stop();  to stop the loop. turned out to be pretty simple in the end